# How to get security token and then navigate to our app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, access-token

I'm building an app using OpenID authentication,I loaded the data(Google,Yahoo,Facebook) in UITableview from URL,once i click that it redirects to the login page in UIWebview.

When I login Google or some other the page is showing an empty.

Now I want to redirect to my application once i logged in.How to get security token?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Step 1`:  you need to define callback URL in the Application setting panel of Google, facebook, Twitter, Instagram etc.,
    For that login with you developer account, goto manage app section of respective provider, and set your callback URL accordingly,
    I give you example of callback URL in Instagram
    eg. "ig://authorize"
    CALLBACK URL/URI : ig123456789012345://authorize
    here `ig` stands for instagram, if its facebook use fb1233454667://authorize

`Step 2`: in Your AppDelegate file write Callback Handler methods

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [self.instagram handleOpenURL:url];
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [self.instagram handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

`Step 3`: Set URL Types in Your apps setting , .[image: refer following screenshot for detail]

`Step 4`: Thats all now you can make request for authentication and after successfull authentication your app will be lauched.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply